# NHibernate - Check if entitiy is out of date/sync

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I am using (fluent) nhibernate in my project. Let's say that I have a transient entity, A, being stored. Then at some point, part of the data store that is related to that entity is updated.

Is there a way to know that the entity A is out of date/sync so that I can go ahead and refresh it ?

Comment: have a look at [this project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/108921/Keeping-Entity-State-Over-Multiple-NHibernate-Sess), its provide, `IsChanged`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually `version` column is used to determine that, and it could be a number, where with each persist it updates the number, or it could be a `datetime` where last persisted time is stored.

When an entity is updated the version column is updated, assume entity A,

```
class A
{
   int Id { get; set; }
   int Version { get; set; }
   string Name { get; set; }
}

class AMap : ClassMap<A>
{
   public AMap()
   {
      Id (x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.Native();
      Version (x => x.Version);
      Map(x => x.Name);
   }
}
```

when entity A is updated the generated SQL like,

```
update A set.... where Id = ? and Version = ?
```

So, if A is already updated by some other transaction this will fail to update and throw an exception. On the exception you should be able to reload and retry.

Make sure to use a new session when you retry.

Comment: Thanks, I like the idea but is there way to automatize updating the version number by something like a trigger or interceptor ? It can be difficult to manually do it everywhere

Comment: As soon as you set the type as version, NHibernate takes care of updating the version, so you don't have to worry about it. Try it out :)